# Model doesn't stop light

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello community!

I'm building a gazebo track where I need the light from a light bulb (simulated as a white sphere with a pointlight) to be stopped by the model's wall so that way the light does not reach to other parts of the track. But, the light seems to go through the model's walls and reaches more zones than desired.

[image: image description]

In the image, we can see that light reaches the other end of the track. This happens becasue the light goes through the red wall, illuminates one side of the yellow wall and then goes through the yellow wall, reaching the other end. Also, notice that one side of the green wall -not visible in the image- is illuminated but the other side isn't, and the light still reaches outside the track.

Note: The pointlight is very close to the ground, so that discards that the problem is happening because the light illuminates the whole track from above. Note 2: Simulating with a spotlight seems to have no different effect.

So the question is, How can we stop the light from going through the wall so that way it doesn't reach the other part of the track? How can we make the lights stay trapped in the track's walls?

As always, thanks for your awsome help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18079/model-doesn%27t-stop-light/) by [imstevenpm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3874/imstevenpm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imstevenpm](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3874/imstevenpm/) on 2017-12-11**:
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, it is a known issue that spot and point lights don't cast shadows, only directional lights do:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2083/point-and-spot-lights-dont-cast-shadows

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1